# T4MVC support for TypeScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript, t4mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC (5) application I am using T4MVC to prevent magic strings appear in my views.

However it is common that I need an Url in my JavaScript or TypeScript code especially when doing AJAX requests.

Currently I am using Razor code in my views to set JavaScript variables to hold the urls:

```
window['myJavaScripVariableName'] = '@Url.Action(MVC.Progress.MyActionMethodName())';
```

then accessing them from .js and .ts code files like:

```
$.get(window['myJavaScripVariableName'], { operationCategory: this.operationCategory })
    .done((data) => {...
```

However this quickly became boring when there are dozens of Url to pass, not talking about the possibility that I make a typo in `myJavaScripVariableName` in one of its two appearances.

Is there any support to not to hardcode the Url literals in JavaScript / TypeScript?

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you using so many url strings ?

Comment: Do you mean why do I have so many urls (routes) to call from AJAX?

Comment: Well I mean, I don't know your structure at all, but maybe have a single dataService URL for xRegion for example, and handle it more on the routing, that said, im really not partial to Razor at all so I can't offer any decisive advice! :(

Answer (score 1):

> However this quickly became boring when there are dozens of Url to pass, not talking about the possibility that I make a typo in myJavaScripVariableName in one of its two appearances.

You need to look at C# -> TypeScript Code Generation. For C# there are various options the most popular being http://type.litesolutions.net/